# Hibernate HQL select the next business day after a given year, month and day

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

good afternoon everyone,

I have a question regarding Hibernate and HQL.

i have a **CALENDAR** table which has the following fields:

```
ID, YEAR, MONTH, DAY, DAY_TYPE
```

i also have a **DAYTYPE** table which has the following fields:

```
ID, DAYTYPE_DESC, BC_HOLIDAY, AB_HOLIDAY, ON_HOLIDAY...
```

the DAYTYPE table looks something like this, indicate holidays for each country.
1 being the holiday, 0 being a business day.

```
ID | DAYTYPE_DESC   | US_HOLIDAY | CA_HOLIDAY | 

1  | Business Day   |          0 |          0 |

2  | Weekend        |          1 |          1 | 

3  | Business Day   |          0 |          0 |

4  |Presidents' Day |          1 |          0 |

5  |Canada's Day    |          0 |          1 |
```

the input is year, month, day, DayType.

the DayType is something like this:

```
class DayType{
  private Long id;
    private String description;
    private Boolean isUSHoliday ;
    private Boolean isCAHoliday;
}
```

how do i write a HQL query to select the next business day by the giving input?

thank you very much!

Comment: oops, for the  DAYTYPE table , please ignore row 3

Comment: your question is not clear enough, can you clearify more please?

Comment: if the input is year = 2016, month = 2, day = 28, DayType(isUSHoliday = 0, isCAHoliday = 1).  then the query should look up CALENDAR table to find the next business day with DAY_TYPE field != {2, 5}, probably will return 2016-2-29

Answer (score 0):

first find the list of DayType ids that are not business days

```
Query notInDayTypeQuery = session.createQuery("FROM DayType WHERE isCAHoliday = 1 OR description = 'Weekend'");
notInDayTypeList = notInDayTypeQuery.list();
```

then find the next date not in that list

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Calendar WHERE DayType NOT IN (:notInDayTypeList) AND ((year=:year AND month=:month AND day>=:day) OR  (year=:year AND month>:month) OR year>:year) ORDER BY year, month, day");
        query.setInteger("year", year);
        query.setInteger("month", month);
        query.setInteger("day", day);
        query.setParameterList("notInDayTypeList", notInDayTypeList);
        resultList = query.list();
```

the first element of resultList will be the date